# Where is the difference between express.js and angular.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, frameworks

I'm new to JavaScript server developement. I recognized the "mean" stack. MongoDB, Express.js, Angular.js and node.js. Where is the difference between express.js and anguar.js and do I need both at the same time?

Comment: Angular runs on the client, whereas Express runs on the server.

Comment: and they can be used independent of eachother.

Comment: **scratches head** Really? Have you even looked at the respective library's websites? After a good 10 minutes it should become pretty crystal clear..

Comment: Now you need just one by using google ;)

Comment: consider express.io as REST web services, and angular as application javascript library loaded on client, we hit REST web services using ajax earlier now angular is doing that in same manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular Js is a client side framework, as Backbone.js, Ember.js, Batman.js, Sammy.js.
I recommand you to look at the sample of this repository :
https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc

It's a comparative of many javascript client side frameworks.

Express Js is a web application framework for node js, it's a couch (Frenglish that means layer) that's permit to host easily a web server with Node.js.